# Proving no matrix of given order can exist over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

I was asked to show in an exercise that for a prime $ p $, in the group $ GL(n,F_p) $ of invertible matrices of dimension $ 1 \leq n \leq p $ mod $ p $, that no matrix can have order $ p^2 $, meaning that no invertible matrix over $F_p$ has $ A^{p^2}=I $ and for all $ k\leq p^2 $ one has $ A^k\neq I $.

I thought about the equation $ A^{p^2} - I = 0 $ and how the minimal polynomial must divide it. The polynomial in the equation decomposes as $ \lambda ^ {p^2} -1 = (\lambda -1)(1+\lambda +\dots+\lambda^{p^2-1}) $ but I cannot proceed from here. Can anyone please help? I thank all helpers.

Comment: In characteristic $p$, $\lambda^{p^2}-1=(\lambda-1)^{p^2}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg : Thank you!

Comment: Could you solve it from there?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg : yes thanks that was what I was missing

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $1\leq n\leq p$, since there certainly are matrices of order $p^2$ in $GL(n,F_p)$ for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lambda^{p^2}-1=(\lambda-1)^{p^2}$, all eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$. If $N$ is the nilpotent part of $A$, then $A=I+N$. We then have that $A^p=I+N^p=I$ since $N^p=0$ given that $n\leq p$, so $A$ has order at most $p$.